# pyplot: Add graph to existing plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

In order to draw two graphs in one plot with python's matplotlib.pyplot, one would typically do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
ydata1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
ydata2 = [0, 0.5, 2, 4.5, 8]

plt.plot(xdata, ydata1, 'r-', xdata, ydata2, 'b--')
plt.show()
```

However, I would like to draw the second dataset only under certain circumstances, like this:

```
plt.plot(xdata, ydata1, 'r-')

if DrawSecondDataset:
    plt.plot(data, ydata2, 'b--')
```

Unfortunately, calling `plot` for the second time means that the first dataset is erased.

How can you add a graph to an already existing plot?

EDIT:

As the answers pointed out correctly, the dataset is only erased if `plt.show()` has been called between the two `plt.plot()` commands. Thus, the example above actually shows both datasets.

For completeness: Is there an option to add a graph to an existing plot on which `plt.show()` has already been called? Such as

```
plt.plot(xdata, ydata1, 'r-')
plt.show()

...

plt.plot(data, ydata2, 'b--')
plt.show()
```

Comment: "Unfortunately, calling plot for the second time means that the first dataset is erased" No it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It only is when you call `show` in between. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Just call `show()` at the very end.

Comment: Yes, that works. But only if you haven't called `show` before. Do you also know how to add a graph after `show` has been called.

Comment: To answer my own question: After you have called `show`, the next `plot` command will clear the plot. Then, you can again call `plot` twice to add two plots. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
if DrawSecondDataset:
    plt.plot(data, ydata2, 'b--')
    plt.show() #to display it
```

Answer (score 0):

The first data won't be erased in this way

```
plt.plot(xdata, ydata1, 'r-')

if DrawSecondDataset:
    plt.plot(data, ydata2, 'b--')

plt.show()
```